# Live stream in openCv using Android IP Camera (python)

Tags: android, python, opencv, stream

I want to make a live stream in openCv using Android IP Camera, I have been trying with this code, but it doesn't work.
What should I change in this code?

```
camera=cv.CaptureFromFile("http://192.168.0.10:8080/videofeed")
while True :
  img =cv.QueryFrame(camera)
  cv.ShowImage('Video',img)
  if cv.WaitKey(0):
    break   
cv.ReleaseCapture(camera)
```

Comment: What do you mean saying it doesn't work? It crashes? It hangs? It produces no output?

Comment: No video output, just a blank screen

Comment: Have you made sure the camera is reachable and produces (non-blank) output? Have you tried displaying just a single frame?

Comment: If displaying a single frame works, I guess the problem is that your loop updates too fast... try adding a sleep statement in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib



url = 'http://192.168.1.183:8080/shot.jpg'

while True:
    imgResp = urllib.urlopen(url)
    img = np.array(bytearray(imgResp.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
    img1 = cv2.imdecode(img, -1)
    #hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    #lower_red = np.array([30,150,50])
    #upper_red = np.array([255,255,180])
    #mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    #res = cv2.bitwise_and(img1, img1, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow('img',img1)
    cv2.waitKey(10)
```